# Nativescript Video observe current time for playFromUrl

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

Using nativescript video plugin there a way to put a spinner up for a video that is loading from a url?

I see this in the documentation:

```
Observable Properties
currentTime() - Current time of video.
```

But I don't see an example of how to use it.

Comment: Can you please be more specific which plugin you are using? As far I recall `playFromUrl` method exists only in `nativescript-audio` plugin, wondering since you are asking about video in your question.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I should have said it is bound to [src]="videoSrc". It looks as though there is an event I should be able to listen to, but it isn't working for me.  this._videoPlayer.addEventListener(this._videoPlayer.playbackStartEvent, (data:EventData)=>{
            console.log("Event was: ", data);
            this.isVideoReady = true;
        });